# Prove algebraically that ${n\choose k}=\frac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot ...\cdot k}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

From the definition of binomial coefficient, $${n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\Rightarrow \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{k!}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}=n(n-1)...(n-k+1)$$

Could someone explain how to derive the last equation algebraically?

Comment: $$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\\=\frac {n(n-1)...(n-k+1)\color{red}{(n-k)!}}{\color{red}{(n-k)!}}\\=n(n-1)...(n-k+1)$$

Comment: it is not an equation, but equality. One must apply the definition of factorial.

Comment: You want the derivation of $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}=n(n-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n-k+1)!$? That just follows immediately from the definition of the factorial $!$.

Comment: What do you mean?  Those are simply definitions aren't they?  Do you really need to have $b*x = b*y \implies x = y$ (if $b \ne 0$), do you?

Answer (score 2):

I will show it using induction. Observe that
$$ \frac{k}{(k-k)!} = k(k-1)\dots(k-k+1)
$$
Hence the case holds for $n = k$. Suppose that it holds for $n - 1$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}
&= \frac{n (n-1)!}{(n-k) (n-k-1)!}\\
&= \frac{n}{(n-k)} (n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-k)\\
&= n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-k+1)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: You are using the equation ${n\choose k}=\frac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{k!}$ that needs to be proven.

Comment: @user300044 I updated it

Answer (score 0):

from equations 
$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$ and$$\binom{n}{0}=1$$ we get
$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\frac{n}{k}\frac{n-1}{k-1}\binom{n-2}{k-2}=\frac{n}{k}\frac{n-1}{k-1}\frac{n-2}{k-2}\binom{n-3}{k-3}=$$ 
$$=\frac{n}{k}\frac{n-1}{k-1}\frac{n-2}{k-2}...\frac{n-(k-1)}{k-(k-1)}\binom{n-k}{k-k}=$$
$$=\frac{n}{k}\frac{n-1}{k-1}\frac{n-2}{k-2}...\frac{n-(k-1)}{1}\binom{n-k}{0}=$$

Answer (score 0):

Seriously?

$n! = n*(n-1)...........*3*2*1$

$(n-k)! = (n-k)*...... *3*2*1$

So $\frac {n!}{(n-k)!} =  \frac {n*(n-1)*.....*(n-k + 1)(n-k)*(n-k - 1)*....*3*2*1}{(n-k)*(n-k - 1)*....*3*2*1} = n*(n-1)*.....*(n-k + 1)$

And $\frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac 1 {k!}\frac {n!}{(n-k)!} = \frac 1 {k!}n*(n-1)*.....*(n-k + 1) = \frac{n*(n-1)*.....*(n-k + 1)}{k!}$.

The only thing that needs proving is that conceptually that ${n \choose k}$ conceptually can be solved by the expression $\frac{n*(n-1)*.....*(n-k + 1)}{k!}$

Which is... to choose $k$ items from $n$ items with regard to order, you have $n$ choices for the first.  For the second you have any choice from the remaining $n-1$ items and so on.  For any $i$th item you have may chose any of the $n-i$ remaining choices.

In total that is $n*(n-1)*.......*(n-k +1)$ or $\frac {n!}{(n-k)!}$ ways of choosing... *with regard to order*.

Without regard to order any of the various ways to arrange the $k$ items are equivalent.  So #of ways to choose k from n without regard to order = $\frac {\text{# ways with order}}{\text{#number of ways to order k items}}$.

To arrange $k$ items, you have $k$ options for the first item, any of the $k-1$ remaining options for the second and so on.  so #number of ways to order k items = $k!$.

So  ${n \choose k}= \text{#of ways to choose k from n without regard to order} = \frac {\text{# ways with order}}{\text{#number of ways to order k items}} = \frac{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}}{k!} = \frac{n1}{k!(n-k)!}$